# sending zip file to php server

Tags: php, ios, zip

I am sending a zip file that contains images from ios app via HTTPREQUEST and the file is the body of the HTTPREQUEST , I need help in writing php simple server that takes this zip file and return the names of the images in the zip file via atext file to the ios app, what should I do?
and where is the zip file located after sending it to the local xammp server?
I have used the $_POST and $_FILES to see if these variables have the zip file that was sent, is that right?
is there anyway of getting the images names without unzipping the sent file?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Three possible approaches:

1. I would have thought you could use the [PHP zip functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php) (such as [`zip_entry_name`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-name.php)) to get the names of the files, without actually unzipping the files themselves.
2. It seems that you could construct your iOS request such that it provides not only the zip file, but also a list of images included in the zip file. If you go that approach, a JSON-based request (with an array of image names and the base 64 encoded zip file) might make sense.
3. You could upload the image files individually (and if you use concurrent requests, you might get comparable performance). While, at first blush, this might seem very inefficient, as you move to iOS7's `NSURLSession`, having discrete uploads, might be useful.

Comment: I need to upload the images at once not individually moreover I dont need to deal with anything regarding JSON-based request, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user2960510 Then it sounds like the [PHP zip functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php) are precisely what you need. Good luck!